# How to fill all area of a SimpleDraweeView?

Tags: android, fresco

I use fresco library. But my image doesn't show normally.

[image]

How can I fill all the area with my image?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/darkRedTransp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

    </ImageView>
    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="fitCenter"
        fresco:overlayImage = "@drawable/ic_med"
        android:layout_marginTop="-78dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        fresco:roundingBorderWidth="12dp"
        fresco:roundingBorderColor="@color/white"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: show some code..

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a different scale type. For example, `fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"` to fill the whole Viewport. Fresco does support a variety of scale types and you can even specify your own implementation. See https://frescolib.org/docs/scaletypes.html for a list of all currently supported scale types.